# how can I store each instance of the loop?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, while-loop, iteration

I have the following methods that allow a user to ask for a drink up to 6 times. Each time they select a drink it may be a new, or the same drink from the menu list. How do I record the user response within each loop?

```
def display
  menu_list = AlcoholicBeverage.pluck(:cocktail_name)
  puts menu_list
  sleep(0.1)
  puts "So, what's your poison?" "\n" 
end

def drink_valid?
  chosen_cocktail = gets.chomp.titleize
  until AlcoholicBeverage.find_by(cocktail_name: chosen_cocktail)
    puts "Sorry please choose something on the list!"
    chosen_cocktail = gets.chomp.titleize
  end

  puts "Mmmm good choice!"
  puts "Now that you've chosen your cocktail, I'll provide you with details on the necessary ingredients,glass and garnishes!"

  glass_type = AlcoholicBeverage.where(cocktail_name: chosen_cocktail).map(&:glass)
  puts "Required : #{glass_type.join.titleize} glass."

  garnish = AlcoholicBeverage.where(cocktail_name: chosen_cocktail).map(&:garnish)
  if garnish.join.titleize == ""
    puts "No garnish needed!"
  else
    puts "Required garnish: #{garnish.join.titleize}"
  end

  preparation = AlcoholicBeverage.where(cocktail_name: chosen_cocktail).pluck("preparation")
  puts "To prepare : #{preparation.join}"
end

def ask
  counter=0
  while counter < 6
    puts "Would you like another drink (yes/no)?"
    new_drink = gets.chomp.strip.titleize

    if new_drink == "Yes" || new_drink == "yes"
      display
      drink_valid?
    else
      puts "I'll give your blood alcohol content level based on the drinks you've had."
    end
    counter +=1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture user input repeatedly by adding the user input to a variable from outside the loop:

```rb
# main.rb
inputs = []
until inputs.size >= 6
  puts "Please input a value or leave blank to exit"
  input = gets.chomp
  break if input == ""
  inputs << input
end

puts "You have input the following: #{inputs.inspect}"
```

```
$ ruby main.rb
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
1
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
2
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
3
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
4
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
5
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
6
You have input the following: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
$ ruby main.rb
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
1
Please input a value or leave blank to exit
2
Please input a value or leave blank to exit

You have input the following: ["1", "2"]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be inserting the gets values into the array when I try this. Just keep getting an empty array on every loop.

Comment: Did you assign `input = []` outside of the loop? Its kind of hard to help you with your code since its not an minimal reproducable example and has so many bits and bobs sticking out all over the place.

Comment: actually I got it to work.Only issue now is that it saves each additional instance but not the first instance (which I recorded in a different method). So I guess I have to play with it and figure out how to rearrange it. Let me know if you see a simple way in doing so. Thanks for your help, you're great!!!!